# Filter out IP using regex and sed

Tags: regex, linux, command-line, sed

I'm having real trouble converting my regular expression into a working sed command on Centos 5.5.

I want to filter the IP address out of a string:

```
"example.org has address 123.45.67.890" -> "123.45.67.890"
```

My regular expression so far is:

```
/([a-zA-Z\. ]+)([0-9\.]+)/
```

And an example of my command using sed is:

```
host example.org | grep 'has address' | sed 's/\([a-zA-Z\\. ]+\)\([0-9\\.]+\)/\2/'
```

But all I get back from that command is the input to sed: "example.org has address 123.45.67.890"

Any ideas?

Comment: this shoudl be on a unix **user** site not a programming site, as sed is standard command line tool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
host example.org | awk '/has address/ {print $4 }'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very simple way to do it without a regex:

```
host example.org | grep "has addres" | awk '{print $4}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need `sed` for this.  You could use `cut` instead to parse the spaces:

```
host example.org | grep 'has address' | cut -d' ' -f4
```

This just takes the 4th word, when delimited by spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Your `([a-zA-Z\. ]+)` captures everything before the IP address and includes that in the match. It will also cause matching to fail if the domain name has any numbers in it. Use a lookbehind:

```
/(?<has address )\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/
```

You apparently [need to use Perl mode for sed to support lookbehinds](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq6.html). You could also use capture groups. If you want a more discriminating pattern (i.e. only match stuff that looks very strongly like an IP address), you can try this:

```
/(?<has address )(?:(?:[01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:[01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\b/
```

That should match four numbers from 0-255, delimited by dots and preceded by 'has address '.

Comment: Perl mode applies to a customized version of `sed` called `ssed`.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `grep`:

```
host example.org | grep -Po '.*has address \K[0-9.]*'
```

Answer (score 0):

host exmaple.org | sed -n 's/^.* (.*)$/\1/p'